# Importing NPM package to Meteor with a hyphen/dash (streaker-js)

Tags: meteor, npm

I am trying to import the npm package [streaker-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streaker-js) into my Meteor app, but I think there is a problem with it having a dash/hyphen in the name.

Installing it with

```
meteor npm install --save streaker-js
```

is fine.

But when trying to import in the client side code with

```
import streaker-js from 'streaker-js';
```

I get an error:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:                   

   While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
   client/main.js:4:15: Unexpected token (4:15)

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

My reasoning is that there is an issue with importing NPM packages that has a dash in the name.

So, how would you import **streaker-js** into Meteor?

Answer (score 2):

javascript variables can't have a hyphen in them.
try this:

```
import streaker from 'streaker-js'

// Assuming the date is currently new Date(2012, 6, 8) : 
var dates = [ new Date(2012, 6, 6), new Date(2012, 6, 7), new Date(2012, 6, 8) ];
var currentStreak = streaker(dates).current(); // 3 

var datesWithoutToday = [ new Date(2012, 6, 6), new Date(2012, 6, 7) ];
var currentStreak = streaker(datesWithoutToday).current(); // 2 - the streak isn't broken until the end of the day 

var datesWithoutTodayOrYesterday = [ new Date(2012, 6, 6) ];
var currentStreak = streaker(datesWithoutTodayOrYesterday).current(); // 0 - the streak is broken as of today
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and enlightenment about the hyphen! This is what I get trying your modification, in the terminal:
`=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/

Unable to resolve some modules:

  "streaker.js" in
/Users/gustav/code/meteor/newtest/node_modules/streaker-js/package.json
(web.browser)

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

  meteor npm install --save streaker.js`

Comment: Also, in the browser console: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'streaker-js'`

Comment: looks like that npm package is almost 4 years old and not maintained.  the maintainer seems to be active on github though, so try putting an issue in on github.  maybe he can update the package to work for you.